# My object oriented program is getting stuck in my first if clause

Tags: python, class, random

Regarding the same problem in my last question, but now my program is running fine but not returning what i want. The question is:
Write a class called Password_manager. The class should have a list called old_passwords
that holds all of the user’s past passwords. The last item of the list is the user’s current password. There should be a method called get_password that returns the current password
and a method called set_password that sets the user’s password. The set_password
method should only change the password if the attempted password is different from all
the user’s past passwords. Finally, create a method called is_correct that receives a string
and returns a boolean True or False depending on whether the string is equal to the current
password or not.

I have created a list of 5 letters.
Next i defined my class and three instance methods.
First method - get_password which returns the last letter in my list;
Second method - set_password. If the letter i input is not in my list i need to return another number, randomly generated.
Third and last method -  method that returns bollean expressions. If the letter i input is the current letter (last one in the list) i return True, else i return False.

```
import random

old_password=['a','b','c','d']

class Password_manager:

  def __init__(self,old_password):
    self.old_password=old_password

  def get_password(self):
    return self.old_password[len(self.old_password)-1]

  def set_password(self):
    if string not in self.old_password:
      return random.choice(self.old_password)

  def is_correct(self):
    current_password=self.get_password()
    if string==current_password:
      return True
    else:
      return False

string=Password_manager(input('Digit password\n'))
print(string.is_correct())
```

My program always return False whenever i input a letter that exists in my list or any other letter. Basically my program skips the first if clause.

Comment: One short remark: You can rewrite `self.old_password[len(self.old_password)-1]` as `self.old_password[-1]`. `[-1]` will always address the last item of a list.

Comment: Style tip: I don't think it's a good idea to do `string=Password_manager(...)`, because `Password_manager` instances are not strings. Since Python is implicitly typed, you should choose names that make it obvious what type each object is. Otherwise, you might get confused and do something like `if string==current_password:`, which won't work because comparing a Password_manager instance against an actual string will always return False.

Comment: Where is the requested list `old_passwords` in your class? There is `old_password` but that value is set to a string during initialization. Overall your code looks as if you just invented some lines of code without thinking about what they do.

Comment: "The class should have a list called old_passwords that holds all of the user’s past passwords." - I don't see this list in your class' definition, nor is there any usage of this list. Nor does `self.old_password` hold all the user's previous passwords (not the current password alone), for that matter.

Comment: use `print(string, current_password)` to see what you have in varables. It should help you to see problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed version with comments.

```
class Password_manager:
    def __init__(self):
        # define an empty list for the old passwords
        self.old_passwords = []

    def get_password(self):
        # get the last password from list
        return self.old_passwords[-1]

    def set_password(self, password):
        # does the password already exist?
        if password not in self.old_passwords:
            # add new password to list of old passwords
            self.old_passwords.append(password)

    def is_correct(self, password):
        # check if the given password is the current password and return an appropriate boolean value
        return password == self.get_password()

# create an instance of the password manager
manager = Password_manager()
# prefill the list of old passwords
manager.old_passwords = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
# set a new password
manager.set_password('Monty')
# check password
print(manager.is_correct('baz'))
print(manager.is_correct('Monty'))
```

BTW, according to the StyleGuide for Python Code the class name should be `PasswordManager`.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is `get_password` which is only returning the last character in your old_password  (i.e. `\n`):

```
def get_password(self):
    return self.old_password[len(self.old_password)-1]
```

It should be:

```
def get_password(self):
    return self.old_password[:-1]
```

After you see other errors to fix such as `string` being undefined.

Comment: But to see current password we look at the last element. I'm not quite catching the idea

Comment: @LuísLopes why are you only looking at the last element of the password? That only returns the last character i.e. `\n`?  Aren't you supposed to compare the entire old password i.e. `Digit password`?

Comment: If `old_password` is supposed to be a list of passwords than you need to change your code. You are only storing one string.

Comment: the thing is that i wanted the passwords to be only letters

Comment: Whats that have to do with the `list`? Just iterate through the password and do `isalpha` on each character to verify it is a letter.

Answer (score 0):

The `is_correct` method compares the global variable `string`, a `Password_manager` object, to the local variable `current_password`, a one-letter string. This will always be false, because `Password_manager` and `str` are unrelated types.

I can't give an example of how to correct only that part, because all of your code is different from how you say it should work. For a full rewrite that matches your intended behavior, see @Matthias's answer.

Comment: but i call that string not knowing that was a key reserved word . I call it string but i could call to the variable the name 'letter'

Comment: `string` isn't a keyword. The point is that a `Password_manager` and a `str` can't be equal to each other.